# How to unit test a function with a large input data that is essential for the expected output?

Tags: python, unit-testing, docstring

I have a dilemma in unit testing.

In the following code, the `model.bin` file is very large and takes 10 minutes to load on my system, which hinders the testing efficiency. However, if I use a smaller model, the function does not return the correct output. How can I achieve both fast and accurate testing?

```py
>>> wordEmbedding = WordEmbedding()
>>> wordEmbedding.load_model('model.bin')
>>> wordEmbedding.doesnt_match('sky', 'book','notebook')
sky # This output is expected because the input model is large. Using a smaller model would produce incorrect output.
```

Comment: use juypter lab or jupyter notebook.

Comment: Except in specific cases, the size of the input should not be relevant to test the function. Let's say that your function matches if a list of words is in your huge dataset. The unit test will test if the logic is ok, not if the performance. You can even test the refactoring of the function (better performance for example) with the same unit tests that already exists.